# Cross Domain session in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I need to share session values between domain A and domain B.
I am trying to login to domain B,the code for login and signup are written in domain A. Once logged in the user will be redirected to domain B.The problem i am facing is that i am unable to fetch the unique id of logged in user which is stored in session. Call to login function is made via an API.I am able to store and fetch the session value on the same page. But when i try to fetch the session value in different page, its showing null.

Note: domain B is not a subdomain. They are two different domains. 
Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Are you getting null as response? @IaSdwIB

Comment: Yes. The value is becoming null.

Comment: Up! Up! Up! Up!